# Stuck with nextJS14 useState on clientSide : Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, fetch-api

everyone,

I'm going crazy and I need your help.
I'm practising with NextJS14 but I'm totally stuck on an error, I've looked through the documentation, checked the various forums, I feel like I've tested everything without success...

I'm using NextJS14.03 with a MongoDB database.
I have a page where I want to retrieve locations (it works fine, I can see them on the page) then as soon as I integrate useState nothing works, I've tried moving the logic to the parent page, putting "use client", deleting async and so on. Nothing works.

Here's the parent page src/app/(stay-listings)/listing-stay-map/page.tsx :

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import SectionGridHasMap from "../SectionGridHasMap";

export interface ListingStayMapPageProps {}

const ListingStayMapPage: FC<ListingStayMapPageProps> = ({}) => {
  return (
    <div className="container pb-24 lg:pb-28 2xl:pl-10 xl:pr-0 xl:max-w-none">
      <SectionGridHasMap />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListingStayMapPage;
```

Then I get my events on this page and try to display a Google map next to it, but as soon as I integrate the useState nothing works and I get the error "Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server."

src/app/(stay-listings)/SectionGridHasMap.tsx :

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import Pagination from "@/shared/Pagination";
import TabFilters from "./TabFilters";
import Heading2 from "@/shared/Heading2";
import EventCard from "@/components/cards/event-card";

const defaultMapProps = {
  center: {
    lat: 59.95,
    lng: 30.33
  },
  zoom: 11
};

const SectionGridHasMap = ({ className = "" }) => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEvents = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/events", {
          cache: "no-store",
        });

        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch events");
        }

        const data = await res.json();
        setEvents(data.events);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error loading events: ", error);
      }
    };

    fetchEvents();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="relative flex min-h-screen">
      <div className={`nc-SectionGridFilterCard flex-1 ${className}`} data-nc-id="SectionGridFilterCard">
        <Heading2 />
        <div className="mb-8 lg:mb-11">
          <TabFilters />
        </div>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 md:gap-8 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
          {events.map((event, index) => (
            <EventCard key={index} event={event} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="flex mt-16 justify-center items-center">
          <Pagination />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="w-full h-full lg:w-1/2">
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY' }}
          defaultCenter={defaultMapProps.center}
          defaultZoom={defaultMapProps.zoom}
        >

        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SectionGridHasMap;
```

Many thanks in advance for your help, I'm really going crazy here :'(

I've tried using client on different pages, moving the logic to the parent page, using different fetch methods and so on.

Comment: "_as soon as I integrate useState nothing works_" In your case, you don't need useState because you can convert your server component to an `async` component. [See Fetching Data on the Server with fetch](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch) that's all I can do without a working example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already try what they said in this page but same issue :'(

Comment: If you add a minimal example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or other platforms like codesandbox, me and others could collaborate and help you.